# barplot with ggplot: colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
> dput(arrivalsITA)
structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L
), month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), arrivals = c(2171, 3335, 5459, 
15679, 14599, 22641, 24031, 24774, 26107, 0, 0, 0, 3528, 4353, 
2283, 16063, 21221, 22905, 23186, 22607, 15922, 0, 0, 0), date = structure(c(16071, 
16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date")), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "arrivals", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

In order to draw a barplot with ggplot I have done:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = arrivalsITA, aes(x=date, y=arrivals, fill=-arrivalsITA$arrivals, label=arrivals, colour=-arrivalsITA$arrivals)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ geom_text(col="black",nudge_y = 1)
```

obtaining the following picture:
[image]

How can I use the heat.colors() function in order to have red for high values of arrivals?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient.html). You'll need `scale_fill_gradientn(colours = heat.colors(10))`. Also, don't use `$` notation inside `aes()`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097183/generating-a-heatmap-using-r-or-python